# How to make Button overlap CardView at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-cardview

I am creating an app that displays announcements, and I want to add a login. I am trying to make this XML design, [image]. 
I want the button to **OVERLAP** the CardView at the bottom and center of it. 
If it's necessary I'll change the root of the file.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#fff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.crescendo.lldm.crescendo.A_Login">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_one_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_one_login"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl_two_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/tv_one_login"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:text="C R E S C E N D O"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_one_login"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:text="FOR THE USA MONUMENTAL CHOIR"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        android:id="@+id/cv_one_login"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#fcfcfc"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_one_login"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what I get in my XML design, [IMAGE2](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/113593249919921939624/6498096095815566674?authkey=COzm8KrMxp6TLw) Hope there is a solution. Thank you!

Comment: You can use frame layout or relative layout with button bottom view with negative top margin. But do remember below lollipop you have to provide bottom button view elevation more than card view

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_two_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_one_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C R E S C E N D O"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_one_login"
            android:text="FOR THE USA MONUMENTAL CHOIR"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_one_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#fcfcfc"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Nilu" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Nilu" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Nilu" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cv_one_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
            android:elevation="15dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could do this pretty easily with the [Constraint Layout library](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) and with the design tab.

[Sample photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfxqt.png)

Here's the code but I did most of this in the design tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/credentials_card"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.281">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username_field"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:hint="Username"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passworld_field"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_field" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Login!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/credentials_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/credentials_card" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Ty buddy this is working and best while using constraint layout. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: But i am unable to add this button with elevation.

Answer (score 6):

Using ConstraintLayout this issue can solve :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_blank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_logo"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_facebook"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/credentials_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_logo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:text="SIGN IN"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="USERNAME"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="PASSWORD"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"
        android:text="S I G N  I N"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/credentials_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="FORGET PASSWORD"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_40"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the `btn_rounded_primary`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">

        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:radius="60dp" android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                    <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
                    <size android:width="110dp" android:height="40dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">

        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:radius="60dp" android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                    <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
                    <size android:width="110dp" android:height="40dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </item>

    <item>

        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:radius="60dp" android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
                    <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
                    <size android:width="110dp" android:height="40dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </item>
</selector>
```

Here is the dimens.xml:

```
<!--genaral spacing-->
<dimen name="spacing_xsmall">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_small">3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_medium">5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xmedium">7dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_middle">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_large">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_smlarge">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_mlarge">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_mxlarge">25dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xlarge">35dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xmlarge">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xxlarge">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xxxlarge">55dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appbar_padding_top">8dp</dimen>
```

colors.xml

```
<color name="grey_3">#f7f7f7</color>
<color name="grey_5">#f2f2f2</color>
<color name="grey_10">#e6e6e6</color>
<color name="grey_20">#cccccc</color>
<color name="grey_40">#999999</color>
<color name="grey_60">#666666</color>
<color name="grey_80">#37474F</color>
<color name="grey_90">#263238</color>
```

**Output using ConstraintLayout:**

[image: Output using ConstraintLayout]

Comment: Don't you think you missed the top constraint for the button? Or is there anything else that takes care of it?

Comment: HI@Rahul, if you want to use `toolbar` then use the `toolbar` code. I submitted this solution without using the `toolbar`. This is a solution for a full-screen pages as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**OutPut**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_one_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_one_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_two_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_one_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C R E S C E N D O"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_one_login"
            android:text="FOR THE USA MONUMENTAL CHOIR"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_one_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#fcfcfc"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_circle"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have read every answer here and I have discarded every single becouse the following motives

1. I don't want to use negative margins, this is not recommended.
2. I don't want to user `LinearLayout`
3. The others answers dosen't work for me

So, finally I have solved my problem just wrapping the `Button` in another `ConstraintLayout` and adding some `elevation` to this `ConstraintLayout`

Here is my result

[image: CardView with over Buttons]

Here is a working sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="28dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="92dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sample_food_1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    style="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_avatar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_description"
                    style="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="Some Button!!"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button_saved_videos"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_saved_videos"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Some Button!!"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button_edit_profile"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code adjust margintop depending on button height. I have set it to -25dp as it is 50dp height

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#fff"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.crescendo.lldm.crescendo.A_Login">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_one_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_one_login"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_background_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:id="@+id/rl_two_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_one_login"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:text="C R E S C E N D O"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_one_login"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:text="FOR THE USA MONUMENTAL CHOIR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            android:id="@+id/cv_one_login"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#fcfcfc"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button        
            android:layout_below="@id/cv_one_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_login"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"></LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        >


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_card_medium"
                    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/margin_card_medium">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium_2">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/login"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular_3x"
                            android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/email"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"/>

                    <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ed_email"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                            android:text="@string/password"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"/>

                    <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/ed_password"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"/>



                        <CheckBox
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/show_password"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                                android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
                                android:buttonTint="@color/secondaryText"
                                android:checked="true"
                        />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shapesignup"

        />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:text="FORGOT PASSWORD?"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_large"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nAJT.png)

**Here background_login**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:angle="225"
            android:startColor="@color/colorBlue"
            android:endColor="#21d6d3" />
</shape>
```