# Cardview with button at bottom

Tags: android, xml

I want to create layout like this
[image]

But I can`t arrange button above cardview. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Button overlap CardView at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745364/how-to-make-button-overlap-cardview-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#48C1F6"
        android:text="Boost" />

</RelativeLayout>
```