# how to use androidx library instead of android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, layout, androidx

i want redesign my app and i have cheack around here for some codes but i conno't find that is updated to compileSdkVersion 30 and using androidX for layouts and not android.support.v7. my SDK is 30. here down is the code i found on this website.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_blank"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_logo"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_facebook"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/credentials_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_logo"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="SIGN IN"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="USERNAME"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="PASSWORD"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"
    android:text="S I G N  I N"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/credentials_card"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="FORGET PASSWORD"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_40"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_up"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

I could'nt comment on the person who posted the code because I did not have a high level for it so I am trying to make a new thread for it.

**OutPut**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDDGA.png)

here is the post i found it from [How to make Button overlap CardView at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745364/how-to-make-button-overlap-cardview-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Hi Diar. You might consider backing up your code and doing: "Refactor -> Migrate to Android X". It will take your entire project to Android X including your CardView.

Comment: hi Elletlar! I got replay from Metrier and that code worked wonderful for me but thanks for your time for replay this qustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new cardview dependency `androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0`.

And in xml use `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView/>` instead of `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView/>`.

Comment: thanks for the replay and this code worked wondeful thanks!.